# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect' at this point

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iminfo/txnot4h1/

I am using ASP MVC VS13.

I am getting the error 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect' at this point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlCars').multiselect();
    $('#ddlCars1').multiselect({
        numberDisplayed: 2,

    });
    $('#ddlCars2').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true

    });
    $('#ddlCars3').multiselect({
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Cars'

    });
});
 </script>
```

I could not find a solution how to run this on my VS13.
I am very new to JS and BootStarp. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The fiddle works fine. What scripts have you included?

Comment: I launch your fiddle page on chrome, no error. However there are lots of issues when searching in google "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error" - jquery and ie 11 related issues

Comment: Yes The fiddle works . But I cant run this in ie 11 and In chrome there are no errors but the page is not as I need.